# MySQL, functional difference between ON and WHERE in specific statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I am studying select queries for MySQL join functions.

I am slightly confused on the below query. I understand the below statement to join attributes from multiple tables with the ON clause, and then filter the results set with the WHERE clause.

Is this correct? What other functionality does this provide? Are there better alternatives?

The tables, attributes, and schema are not relevant to this question, specifically just the ON and WHERE interaction. Thanks in advance for any insight you can provide, appreciated.

```
SELECT DISTINCT Movies.title  
FROM Rentals  
    INNER JOIN Customers 
    INNER JOIN Copies 
    INNER JOIN Movies ON Rentals.customerNum=Customers.customerNum  
        AND Rentals.barcode=Copies.barcode  
        AND Copies.movieNum=Movies.movieNum  
WHERE Customers.givenName='Chad'  
AND Customers.familyName='Black';
```

Comment: Because you are only doing inner joins, the restrictions which appear in the `WHERE` clause could be moved to the `ON` clause without changing the logic.

Comment: Every joined table should have an on clause. You code seems to be a hybrid of  implict joins (comma seperated) and explict joins, Please review join_specification:
    ON search_condition
  | USING (join_column_list) https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: ***Is this correct? What other functionality does this provide? Are there better alternatives?*** — There's no way to answer that without knowing what results you are looking for.

Comment: Your query should do the same thing but be a bit more clear if you move the individual `ON` clauses to their respective joins.  Like this: https://pastebin.com/dNxPFzmu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INNER JOIN` (and the outer joins) are binary operators that should be followed by an `ON` clause.  Your particular syntax works in MySQL, but will not work in any other database (because it is missing two `ON` clauses).

I would recommend writing the query as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT m.title  
FROM Movies m JOIN
     Copies co
     ON co.movieNum = m.movieNum JOIN
     Rentals r
     ON r.barcode = co.barcode JOIN
     Customers c
     ON c.customerNum = r.customerNum
WHERE c.givenName = 'Chad' AND
      c.familyName = 'Black';
```

You should always put the `JOIN` conditions in the `ON` clause, with one `ON` per `JOIN`.  This also introduces table aliases, which make the query easier to write and to read.

The `WHERE` clause has additional filtering conditions.  These could also be in `ON` clauses, but I think the query reads better with them in the `WHERE` clause.  You can glance at the query and see:  "We are getting something from a bunch of tables for Chad Black".

Comment: I'll keep each instance of JOIN and ON together in a query. Cheers, very informative!

Comment: Hey Gordon, a bit off topic but what's the reason that you format your query with the `ON` clause on a separate line along with the following `JOIN` .. It's confusing to me but knowing you I'm sure there is some sound logical reason here.

Comment: @billynoah . . . In the `FROM` clause, I always align the tables right after the `FROM`.  This makes it easy to see the tables -- and to replace them with subqueries.  The `JOIN` goes at the end of the line because I always put binary operators at the end, when they continue to the next line.  As for the `ON`, I find it convenient to have the conditions all indented at the same level, even though they are interleaved with the table names.

Answer (score 0):

Ordinary inner `JOIN` operations only generate result rows for table rows matching their `ON` condition. They suppress any rows that don't match. That means you can move the contents of `ON` clauses to your `WHERE` clause and get the same result set. Still, don't do that; JOINs are easier to understand when they have `ON` clauses.

If you use `LEFT JOIN`, a kind of outer join, you get rows from the first table you mention that don't match any rows in the second table according to the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.a_id = b.a_id
```

gives you are result set containing all rows of `a` with NULL values in `b.name` indicating that the `ON` condition did not match.